# Javascript debugging issue with colorbox

Tags: javascript, debugging, colorbox

Ive recently been making structure and style edits to http://washingtongraphic.com/logo-design.html and found that the colorbox plugin no longer works. When you roll over each logo, it should pop-up to a larger size and go back to its normal state when you roll out. In addition, when clicked, it should appear in the colorbox window… this also does not work. All of the links to the scripts and other resources appear to be correct, but for some reason, the script is not triggered on roll-over and the colorbox window also does not appear when clicked. A functional example (of how it should be working) can be found here: http://washingtongraphic.com/annual-reports.html. Im not very good at debugging javascript yet and can really use all of the help I can get. I have been using firebug but am not sure how to tell where the script is failing. Thank you all in advance.
*Also, I did not create this site but am merely editing it… its not how I would have built it (I know there are some other structure issues here!)*

Comment: Take a look at your Javascript console.  There are a bunch of errors happening on page load.

Comment: I'd also recommend creating a small example page with just a couple of images to narrow down where the problem is occurring.

Comment: All im seeing in the way of errors is ".scrollable" function which I dont think has anything to do with my issue. Are you seeing something different?

Comment: I occasionally see errors with imgOn() and imgOff() when I hover over an image.

Comment: Actually, the imgOn() imgOff() errors aren't the issue either.  Those happen on both pages when you hover over the "Back To Projects" button.

Comment: Yes there are a lot of less-than-optimal code issues on this site; inline css, tables in unnecessary places, etc… Im slowly but surely tryin to be rid of them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the load order of `trialbyfire.js` and `trialbygallery.js`.

Make sure they're loaded in this order (you have them reversed on the logo-design page):

```
<script src="js/trialbygallery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/trialbyfire.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Additionally, to fix this error, you have two choices:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'scrollable' on trialbyfire.js:89`

1. Remove:

   //  Mousewheel
   // execute your scripts when DOM is ready. this is a good habit
   $(function() {

   ```
   // initialize scrollable with mousewheel support
   $(".scrollable").scrollable({ vertical: true, mousewheel: true });
   ```

   });
2. Fix the 'scrollable' dependency.  Likely a plugin that should be loaded, but isn't.

Comment: Load order... trialbyfire.js is loaded second on the page you linked that works and loaded first by the page that is broken.  On the broken page, the error occurs @ trialbyfire.js and then never executes `$.ready` in trialbygallery.js

Comment: Good catch (+1).  But the scrollable error still isn't affecting the hover state of the images.

Comment: There is no way at all I would have figured that out!!Thank the lord for awesome people like you all!! It never even occurred to me that the load order of the scripts would have an effect on their function. I know that ordering document resources is better to be done with all css files grouped and called first, then scripts, etc but I really didnt know the order of the script calls themeselves would create such an issue. FANTASTIC!!